# display parent back history in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, browser-history

I want to display a users previously visited page in an iframe on my page. For example: if a user is on cnn.com, and then they type in mysite.com an click on a button on my page, I was the iframe on my page to display cnn.com.

I have read several solutions online but none have fixed my issue. My current implementation is as follows:

index.html:

```
<body>
        <div>
            <h1>Welcome to mysite!</h1>
            <h3>Click the button to see a site you have previously visited</h3>
            <button id="button">magic</button>
        </div>
        <br>    
        <p>This is a site you visited previously</p>
        <iframe id="myIFrame" height="500px" width="100%" class="netframe" src="example.com"></iframe>

</body>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#button").click(function(e){  
            document.getElementById("button").style.color = "red"; 
            $("#myIFrame").attr('src', parent.history.back());

        });
});
```

The issue I am having is that when I click the button, the entire page goes back, and it is not shown in the iframe. So in my example when I click the button, my entire page goes from mysite.com to cnn.com. Id like the parent page to remain the same, and the iframe to load cnn.com within it.

I have read up on some of the quirks regarding how history is different depending on how you load up an iframe, but none of that has helped me.

If there a way to do what I want to do?

Comment: very unlikely you'll get this working properly due to browser security and due to some websites not allowing themselves to be in a frame. i'm fairly sure that browsers won't allow js to read the history of a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't a thing that you can do. The contents of the user's browser history are generally treated as a secret; you cannot cause the browser to reveal them to you.

In situations where the user navigated to your page by clicking a link on the previous page, you can determine what that page was by checking `document.referrer`. However, this will not be the case if the user entered your page's URL manually, as you describe in your question.

In any case, methods like `history.back()` do not return a value; they cause the frame to navigate to the previous page in its history. There is no way to determine what this page is, and doing so will generally cause your script to stop running (as your page is no longer active).